# Wget large file ends up 503

Tags: 14.04, wget

I'm trying to download a large file 10gb backup file from bluehost cpanel based account.

When i:

```
wget -c http://domain.com/backup.zip
```

I get:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
```

While wget to http://domain.com/favicon.ico and others works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
http://domain.com/backup.zip
```

when put into a web browser give you a download in progress?

HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable
Introduction

The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

Fixing 503 errors

The Web server is effectively 'closed for repair'. It is still functioning minimally because it can at least respond with a 503 status code, but full service is impossible i.e. the Web site is simply unavailable. There are a myriad possible reasons for this, but generally it is because of some human intervention by the operators of the Web server machine. You can usually expect that someone is working on the problem, and normal service will resume as soon as possible.

Please contact the system operators of the Web site (e.g. your ISP) to determine why the service is down. They will be in a much better position to help you than we are for this type of error.

Comment: yes it works fine in browser, only fails in wget

Comment: but after a very long wait time, wget throws 503 earlier than that

Comment: ok its working now, maybe the issue was with server somewhere

thanks :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please feel free to approve my answer with a checkmark.  You are welcome.  :)

Comment: yap done now :)